# Sql loader conditions

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-loader

Can I do something like this in SQL LOADER?

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'table_with_one_million_rows.dat'
INTO TABLE TABLE_WITH_ONE_MILLION_ROWS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
   COL1                     DECIMAL 
 , COL2                     DECIMAL IF COL1='X' '1' else '0'
 , COL3                     CHAR 

)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A condition in SQL*Loader can be performed using `decode`.

Using a `DECIMAL` in your example will get the error:

```
SQL*Loader-402: Unable to determine length of column COL1 from specification
```

Suggest using `DECIMAL EXTERNAL` instead:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'table_with_one_million_rows.dat'
INTO TABLE TABLE_WITH_ONE_MILLION_ROWS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
   COL1                     DECIMAL EXTERNAL
 , COL2                     DECIMAL EXTERNAL "decode(:COL2, 'X', '1', '0')"
 , COL3                     CHAR 

)
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. And another thing if for example I use: decode(:col1,'X','1',decode(:col0,'A','0','-1')) Is this OK?

Comment: You can't use `:col0` as it's not defined. However, if it was defined then, yes, this is allowable. It will set `COL2` to `'1'` if `COL1` is `'X'` else it will set `COL2` to `'A'` if `COL0` is `'0'` else it will set `COL2` to `'-1'`. If you meant to use `:col1` instead of `:col0` then it can be simplified to `decode(:col1,'X','1','A','0','-1')`

Comment: No, I meant to take into consideration both :COL1 and :COL0 to evaluate :COL2.  Something like If elseif else . I`ll give it a try anyway..thanks

Comment: It does not work.. could u please tell me if my syntax is wrong or i`m trying to do sth impossible:                                             `code` C1 POSITION (1:3),                                                        C2 POSITION (4:6),                                                     C3 "DECODE(:C1,'uno',DECODE(:C2,''due'',''Y'',''N''),'N')"